# how to find when a particular software was installed on server?

Tags: linux

Someone just recently hacked my Linux server and installed some software on it. Just to be sure if it was the hacker i want to find out which software were installed and when those software were installed recently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the complete log of the software installed in the `/var/log/dpkg.log` file. You can view it using `sudo nano /var/log/dpkg.log`

Comment: But there are .gz files with the same name too. Do they also contain the same logs?

Comment: That's assuming a) you're using a Debian-based system (e.g. Ubuntu), and b) that the hacker was polite enough to use the package management system, and not smart enough to delete a few lines of the log file when they were done.

Comment: yes they also contain the logs of the installed software history

Comment: Actually the hacker exploited an snmp vulnerability in my server. I just had to make sure that everything was fine. That he didnt make any changes.

Comment: Why aren't all the dpkg logs in the same log file. Why are there so many dpkg files there too?